# Only clicking twice in the 2d sheets view (leftpanel) for PDF files would show them in the Autodesk viewer

Tags: javascript, autodesk, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

Following the discussion of this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39030839/autodesk-forge-viewer-renders-only-single-page-for-pdf-files), I'm able to show the 2d sheets view (leftpanel) in the autodesk viewer for pdf files and other 2d files.

[image]

[image]

But now the problem I have is clicking once on the links in the left panel won't render the view in the viewer, it just shows loading but it won't load. But if you click on the same link once again, it shows up. So, we need to click twice on the same link to get the viewer show that sheet.

**And this problem happens only for "PDF" files. For other 2d files like "DWG" and so on, just single-click would do the job as usual.**

When I click on any sheet it shows this error in the developer console: 
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispose' of null**
[image]

But If I click it again, it shows up correctly.

Not sure what the problem actually is.

Comment: first, please consider user v2.10 instead, this is the latest (as of August/2016)

Comment: @AugustoGoncalves As per this page https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/overview/changelog/, `2.9` seems the latest viewer released so far. And we're using `2.8` right now. Did you mean to use the latest `2.9` instead?

Comment: this page is not yet updates, we're on version 2.10 (August 2016)

Comment: @AugustoGoncalves Okay, thanks we'll use it then. Is there any write-up/changelog anywhere for the things that have changed in `v2.10`?

Comment: we're working to get this public soon... I know we have some improvements around PDF files. have you tried?

Comment: @AugustoGoncalves We just changed to `v2.10` and this issue got fixed and working now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anybody runs into this problem, you can use the latest viewer. We got it fixed using Autodesk Viewer `v2.10` https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/overview/changelog/2.10/.