# Accessing multiple page of pdf file using Autodesk.PDF without transformation on viewer V7

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm using the Viewer V7 and the Autodesk.PDF extension in order to show a multipage pdf. This is a source fragment:

```
var pdf = 'http://localhost/test.pdf';
Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(optionsLocal, function onInitialized() {
    viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(viewerDiv);
    viewer.setTheme("light-theme");
    var errorCode = viewer.start();

    viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.PDF').then( () => {
        viewer.loadModel( pdf, {page: 1}, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
        viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore")
        viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsGui")
        viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.DocumentBrowser")
    });     
});
```

I want to show two buttons to scroll the pdf one page at the time.
How can I determine the number of pages (length) of the pdf? How can I "jump" on the desidered page?

I cannot use the method described on similar posts eg:

> [Autodesk Forge viewer renders only single page for PDF files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39030839/autodesk-forge-viewer-renders-only-single-page-for-pdf-files)

My files are not transformed by derivatives services and I cannot call for example:

```
var viewableItems = Autodesk.Viewing.Document.getSubItemsWithProperties(modelDocument.getRootItem(), {'type':'folder','role':'viewable'}, true);
```

The mentioned onDocumentLoadSuccess callback is unusefull to get the list of viewables because the method loadModel does not pass the document entity.
I'm using the DocumentBrowser extension to navigate the whole pdf but, how can I determine the page choosen by the user?

Thanks for any support.
Gabriele.

Answer (score 0):

According to Forge Viewer's Term of Usage, the Autodesk Forge viewer can only be used to view files generated by Autodesk Forge services

```
/*!
 * LMV 
 * 
 * Copyright 2019 Autodesk, Inc.
 * All rights reserved.
 * 
 * This computer source code and related instructions and comments are the
 * unpublished confidential and proprietary information of Autodesk, Inc.
 * and are protected under Federal copyright and state trade secret law.
 * They may not be disclosed to, copied or used by any third party without
 * the prior written consent of Autodesk, Inc.
 * 
 * Autodesk Forge Viewer Usage Limitations:
 * 
 * The Autodesk Forge viewer can only be used to view files generated by
 * Autodesk Forge services. The Autodesk Forge Viewer JavaScript must be
 * delivered from an Autodesk hosted URL.
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load another extension called `Autodesk.DocumentBrowser` in addition to the `Autodesk.PDF`, It will create a Document Browser window that lists all the pages of the PDF like so:
[image: DocumentBrowser]

See [the documentation for more info](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Extensions/DocumentBrowser/)